# JQuery automatic slide down of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make an effect that the containers slide down one by one automatically. I'm using Bootstrap for formatting the divs and other HTML elements. I modified the code. It displays everything when it loads, it doesn't display things one by one.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var addTime = 500;
    var slide = function(){ 
    $(".main .container").slideDown('slow'); 
    }
    var content = $(".main .container").first();

    setTimeout(function(){ 
    content.slideDown('slow'); 
    }, 500);

    while (content.length !== 0)
    {
        setTimeout(slide, addTime);
        content = content.next();
        addTime *= 5000;
    }
});
```

Comment: Post a complete code example please.

Comment: I think you should use the brackets with `next`. It should be `$(".main .container").next().slideDown('slow');`.